# Right way to replace legacy ad unit IDs with new IDs

Tags: android, admob

I updated to a new AdMob and in "Here's what to do next" section of the new Admob, there is a guide: Replace legacy ad unit IDs with new IDs  (https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/6025739?hl=en)

In upgrade guide it says that you just need to "replace each of the legacy Publisher and Mediation IDs in your app with the corresponding new ad unit IDs".

I have this code

```
        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="a..."
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

and this

```
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "a...");
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Is it enough just to replace "a..." with new ad unit ID "ca-app-pub-...", because on Banners guide on Google developers website it says that this method is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android).

If I need to change code also, can you give me new code that would do the same as my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "new code" requires you to use the google play services library. Follow the official guide on migrating to the new admob [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration). 
The changes you'll need to make in your Activity class are:

Change the lines:

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); 
 adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

to:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(activity);
adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
.build());
```

In your layout, Change the ad xml namespace from:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

To :

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Then in your manifest's application tag, Change:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Add:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Don't forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know is it a problem if I use old version of play services? In my `ANDROID_SDK_PATH\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-se‌​rvices` highest version is `4.3.23` and I installed latest Google Play services (Rev. 16) from Android SDK Manager (I use Android Studio 0.4.5), and here [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) they use `5.0.77`. It also writes on that page that `Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.`. What will happen if I don't use latest version since I don't have it?

Comment: Also, I noticed that you in your code you used `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);`, and not `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);`. Do you think that it is better to use BANNER than SMART_BANNER?

Comment: Ads will still work if you don't use the latest version. You should use SMART_BANNER instead of BANNER since it auto resizes the adview based on the device's screen resolution. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. You used `adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);`. Is that required since I already have `adUnitId` and `adSize` in XML file, or you just wrote that because in my question I also had those things in java code? I tried just using this `adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView); AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); adView.loadAd(adRequest);` and it seems that it works fine, so is that alright?

Comment: Yes, It's alright if you're referencing from xml because the adsize, adunit will be set. I used it because you were constructing the adview via java : "new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "a...")"